# Calculate the sum

Tags: awk, bc

Let’s imagine we have a budget document: budget.txt

The exercise is to calculate the sum column for every product in the month, also to calculate totals in the last row.
You may try to do it in a shell.
How shall it work?

- a program/script shall take a parameter with the filename (not to be hardcoded in the body)
- do the needful
- print output to a screen
- if there’s an error in the data file somewhere, the program/script shall print it on a screen and terminate.

For the bash script, you may try with awk and bc commands.

[image]

I have created a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n " Please write the file name:" 
read file 
awk '{print $0}' $file
```

Comment: I have attached the budget.txt file in.jpeg format

Comment: So, that's your homework. Have you done something? Do you have problem? or a question?

Comment: Hi James, I have tried to do it but as I know basic I couldn't find the solution. I can take the data from the .txt file and print using awk but don't know how to sum the rows and show them in Sum Column

Comment: I have created a shell script
#!/bin/bash
echo -n " Please write the file name:"
read file
awk '{print $0}' $file

Comment: If you [edit] your question to contain a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus your attempt to solve the problem yourself then we can help you. Make sure your question just contains [well-formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text - no images, no links, just text. See [ask] and look at some existing questions that have been upvoted and answered if that's not clear.

Comment: @Aktar Something that might be helpful for learning on this site would be to try to do as much of the problem you can, and then if you need to ask how to do something, or get stuck with an error, try to fix it, then look to see if it's been answered, and if not, ask it and share what you tried! A good programmer needs dedication and determination more than direct homework answers, you can do it!

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying my best

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate what Ed was talking about when requesting text ...
[image: XOne working solution]

And now a pretty-printed, annotated version of the awk bit ...

```
NR == 1 {                              # print the header line (the 1st row/record)
        print
}

NR > 1 && $0 != "Total" {              # for all but the last record (which starts with "Total")
        rsum = 0                       # zero a tally for the entire row
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {    # iterate over every column (field) from the 2nd to the last (NF)
                a[i] += $i             # add each fields value to an array (representing the column)
                rsum += $i             # add each fields value to the sum for the row
        }
        printf "%s\t%3d\n", $0, rsum   # print each row with the sum of the row
        fc = NF                        # store the number of fields for the next operation
        a[NF + 1] += rsum              # and tally the grand total
}

$1 == "Total" {                        # for the last row
        printf "Total\t"               # print "Total"
        for (i = 2; i <= fc; i++) {    # then the array values we added up above
                printf "%3d\t", a[i]
        }
        printf "%3d\n", a[fc + 1]      # followed by the grand total
}
```

Comment: Hi tink: Could you please check if i wrote the code correctly? 

awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1 && $0!="Total" {rsum=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){a[i]+=$i;rsum+=$i};printf "%s\t%3d\n", $0,rsum:fc=NF;a[NF+1]+=rsum} $1=="Total" {printf "Total\t";for(i+2;i<=fc;i++)
{printf "%3d\t",a[i]);printf "%3d\n",a[fc+1])}'

Comment: `awk 'NR==1{print} NR>1 && $0!="Total"{rsum=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){a[i]+=$i;rsum+=$i};printf "%s\t%3d\n", $0,rsum;fc=NF;a[NF+1]+=rsum} $1=="Total"{printf "Total\t";for(i=2;i<=fc;i++){printf "%3d\t",a[i]};printf "%3d\n",a[fc+1] }' budget.txt` @Aktar ... and please, **don't** post images of text :P

Comment: What if I want to run it in a script so I can do something like that that
echo -n "Enter the file name: " 
read file_name

awk.................. at end $file_name

Comment: @Aktar Same thing.  Just replace the `budget.txt` with your `$file`.

Comment: you are awesome. I really appreciate your time and support. Can I have your LinkedIn or Facebook? I want to learn bash shell-scripting

Comment: Yeah nah, sorry, I prefer to help people here (in my own good time and without expectations).  :)  But thanks for the praise, and feel free to accept my answer if it does what you want. @Aktar

Comment: All works except I got the result: 

Butter  4   5  8 11 36 2                              66
Total       37                 66          57    87    68              87      402


something wrong in the last row

Comment: What did you expect, @Aktar?  To me it looks perfectly fine, 402 is the sum for both the last column and the last row, in other words the total spend of all foods over all six months ...

Comment: I expect the Total row shows the sum of one number then show tab then another data. not shows nicely sequencewise

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean ... you want two identical numbers to show in different places? What do you mean by "show tab" @Aktar?

Comment: I can't add the screenshot to show you my output. can you give me your mail address so that I can sent you the screenshot that might helpful to understand my issue

Comment: Just upload to [this](https://pasteboard.co/) and paste the link @Aktar

Comment: How on earth did you achieve **that**?  Can you please paste the actual text of your budget.txt to a public pastebin?  I obviously had to **TYPE** your values from the screenshot of your above; and that renders the screenshot I pasted.  I have no explanation for that latest image of yours. @Aktar

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code which is not full proof. But you can make the amendment on this code as per your future requirement. At the moment I have created the budget.txt file and make sure that all the content on it are separated by Tab. After running this script it is providing the below results.

[image]

This is the code sample (Note: No value is hard-coded on this script):

```
#!/bin/bash

function main {
    file_check
    file_content
    calculation
    exit 0
}

function file_check {
    # Asking to provide the file name or complete path. 
    read -p "Enter the file name: " file_name
    
    # Checking if the file exist else exit the script.
    [ -f "$file_name" ] || { echo "The provided file name does not exist. Terminating the script."; exit 0; }
}

function file_content {
    # Saving the file content of first row and column in arrays. 
    column=($(awk '{ print $1 }' "$file_name"))
    row=($(awk 'FNR == 1 { print }' "$file_name"))
    # Calculating the length of the variables.
    column_length=${#column[@]}
    row_length=${#row[@]}
}

function calculation {
    # To calculate the sum of every item per month. 
    for((i=2;i<$row_length;i++)); do
        num=($(awk -v var="$i" '{print $var}' $file_name | sed '1d;$d'))
        sum=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${num[*]}))")
        search_replace_row
    done
    
    # To calculate the last sum of total.
    num=($(tail -1 $file_name | awk '{$1=""}1'))
    sum=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${num[*]}))")
    search_replace_row

    # To calculate sum of single item for every month.
    for ((i=2;i<$column_length;i++)); do
        num=($(awk "FNR == $i { print }" budget.txt | awk '{$1=""}1'))
        sum=$(IFS=+; echo "$((${num[*]}))")
        search_replace_column
    done
}
function search_replace_row {
    content_row=$(tail -1 "$file_name")
    sed -i "s/$content_row/$content_row\t$sum/" $file_name
}
function search_replace_column {
    content_column=$(sed -n "${i}p" $file_name)
    sed -i "s/$content_column/$content_column\t$sum/g" $file_name
}


main
```